# How can I capture a video with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, capture, windows-movie-maker

I am trying to capture a live video from my digital camera using Windows 7.

Live Movie maker and Windows Movie maker 2.6 do not have "capture" menu item.

Apparently, Windows Movie maker 2.1 has a "capture" menu item. However, I don't know how to download it on Windows 7.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).  Cross platform and free.  [Getting video from a device](http://www.scribd.com/doc/25400/Video-Recording-With-VLC) is pretty easy.

Comment: The second link you've provided no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

I use one note's 'capture video' facility- video is stored in one note itself, but can be saved wherever you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Just use windows internal stuff like: [Windows Media Encoder x64](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Windows-Media-Encoder-fuer-x64_17567989.html) or
[Microsoft Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EncoderPro_Overview.aspx)

Comment: You may want to edit the post and try that second link again.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a web-based method like www.screentoaster.com.  This is free and can be used from any version of Windows Mac OS X, whatever.